# How to implement Form Authentication in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

Can someone provide me a good article on form authentication. How to implement it with the help of screenshot and a easy example. or you can orovide me the link of the article.

Comment: i have used google but not foud any relavent article with screenshot which will help me out if you have some stuff then post it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with the MSDN articles on forms authentication there are examples and set by step guides

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7t6b43z4.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647070.aspx) from Microsoft

```
if (Membership.ValidateUser(userName.Text, password.Text))
{
    if (Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"] != null)
    {
        FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(userName.Text, false);
    }
    else
    {
        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userName.Text, false);
    }
}
else
{
    Response.Write("Invalid UserID and Password");
}
```

Comment: @Nischal-If you got the answer plz do vote and mark it as answer..so that it your question will be closed for the viewers